# How to fetch primarykey from table based on a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 1  | Foo1 |
| 2  | Foo2 |
| 3  | Foo3 |
+----+------+
```

"id" is the primarykey here.

My query:

```
SELECT id FROM tablename where name='Foo1';
```

MYSQL showing only column name but no values.

Comment: 1st try select * from table. then see whether all are displayed correctly.. according to that modify your query

Comment: @dpk Why would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming cases match, there must be some leading and/or trailing whitespaces in data that need to be trimmed in the query:

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE TRIM(name)='Foo1';
```

Otherwise, use `UPPER` in both sides of the `=` to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

try

```
select id from `table` where name = 'Foo1';
```

TABLE is a reserved word, to use it as a table name enclose it in backticks.  Your original query is throwing an error, thus the empty result.

Comment: I don't think errors allow returning empty results. OP is complaining on empty result with column name shown.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to **use LIKE clause while comparing strings** i.e:

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE TRIM(name) LIKE 'Foo1';
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM `table` WHERE name LIKE 'Foo1';
```